# Install python3-gi for Travis-CI and Python >= 3.3

Tags: travis-ci, pygobject, circleci

What is the correct way to install `python3-gi` on Travis-CI using the `.travis.yml` file?

The past recommendation was to use Python 3.2 ([Travis-ci & Gobject introspection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748528/travis-ci-gobject-introspection)), but I would prefer testing against more recent versions.

I did try a few sensible combinations of commands, but my knowledge of the Travis-CI environment is very basic:

This for example fails with and without using `system_site_packages: true`:

```
before_install:
  - sudo apt-get install -qq python3-gi

virtualenv:
  - system_site_packages: true
```

Two examples of repositories that have this working (as far as I can tell):

- https://github.com/ignatenkobrain/gnome-news (CircleCI)
- https://github.com/devassistant/devassistant (Travis-CI)

Answer (score 2):

In order to use a newer version you would either have to build it or use a container system like docker.

[gnome-news](https://github.com/ignatenkobrain/gnome-news/pull/35) has an example of a pygobject project using [circleci](https://circleci.com/) (which is another free alternative to travis-ci). They are using fedora rawhide in docker which has the latest versions of the entire gnome stack.

Comment: Thank you! I will take me some time to learn how to do a `circle.yml`. Will post when I have a solution and accept the answer!